# Button click using Selenium not actionable

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, webdriverwait, execute-script

I am trying to fill in a registration form and click submit.  But Selenium says the Registration button is not actionable.  I have tried using actionchains and a couple of other techniques but generally get the same error.

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
```

My code...

```
driver.get('https://discover.workato.com/automate-2022/p/1?utm_source=Automate+2022&utm_medium=employee+referral&utm_campaign=MCoblentz')
time.sleep(3)

first_name = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="FirstName"]')
first_name.send_keys(line[1])
```

skipping a few more fields to the button click (and neither the by class name or the xpath work)...

```
Button = driver.find_element(By.class name("mktoButtonWrap"))
#    Button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mktoForm_3468"]/div[17]/span')

Button.click()
```

For the life of me, I can't figure out:

1. Why the button is not actionable and what I need to do to click it. ***(Major** problem)*
2. Why Python won't run with the following find_element line *(minor annoyance)*

   ```
   Button = driver.find_element(By.xpath('//*[@id="mktoForm_3468"]/div[17]/span')
   ```

Python is throwing an error that

```
'AttributeError: type object 'By' has no attribute 'xpath'
```

But I'm initializing with:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to consider a couple of things here as follows:

- Instead of:

  ```
  Button = driver.find_element(By.class name("mktoButtonWrap"))
  ```

  It should have been:

  ```
  Button = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "mktoButtonWrap")
  ```

  Similarly,

  ```
  Button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="mktoForm_3468"]/div[17]/span')
  ```
- Further, this error message...

  ```
  selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
  ```

  indicates that the desired element is not interactable.

---

### Solution

To click on <kbd>Register</kbd> you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://discover.workato.com/automate-2022/p/1?utm_source=Automate+2022&utm_medium=employee+referral&utm_campaign=MCoblentz")
  driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='mktoButton' and text()='Register']"))))
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: I'm getting a timeout on the button.  I tried both `Button = driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="mktoForm_3468"]/div[17]/span'))))` and your suggestion; both timed out. The button is always clickable; the form requires all fields to be submitted.  I am filling out the fields before attempting to submit.  Not sure why this is timing out.  Any suggestions, @undetectedSelenium?

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is incorrect. It should be:

```
Button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="mktoForm_3468"]/div[17]/span')
```

If you import By correctly (`from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By`), your IDE should autocorrect and show correct options:
[image]

Comment: In reverse order: thank you @billyzee, for the syntax.  Atom is color-coding ... I must have been off by something subtle.  It's working now.

Comment: as in, your suggested syntax corrections are helping me avoid the warning.  Still have the problem with the button click.